# nc exits immediately, on connection, when run as an upstart job

Tags: upstart, netcat, stdin, nc

I'm using the following `/etc/init/jsonlog.conf` upstart job:

```
description     "jsonlog"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

script
  cd /tmp
  echo "about to listen"
  /bin/nc -l 3333
  echo "finished listening"
end script

post-stop script
  sleep 1
end script
```

The problem is that `nc` exits immediately every time a client connects.

The required behaviour is that all data received (which is utf8 json) should end up in `/var/log/upstart/jsonlog.log`.  This server is running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

The `nc` command works correctly when run from a bash shell.

I'm making an *assumption* that this be something to do with `stdin`.  I've tried using a `-q -1` option, but it hasn't helped.

P.S. I'm fine with the fact that this will listen to only one client at a time.

Comment: -k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option without the -l option.

Comment: -d      Do not attempt to read from stdin.

Comment: Why are you trying to have this solution?

Comment: Why do you want to use `nc` for centralized logging? There are nice dedicated tools that are doing this better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two things going wrong with your `nc` command. You are invoking `nc` in a way intended for two way communication and expect it to perform one way communication.

The `-d` flag can stop `nc` from reading from `stdin` which will get it to do the one-way communication which it appears that you are trying to do.

The other problem is that `nc -l` will by default only service a single connection and then terminate. You can use the `-k` flag to change that behavior.

In all the command thus becomes:

```
nc -dkl 3333
```

It does however seem you are using a tool not designed for the job. Rather than using `nc` I would recommend that you use the syslog protocol and a logger designed to work with that protocol.

Answer (score 2):

`nc -dl` is what you need for the BSD flavor of `nc`.

The `nc` that comes with RHEL7 is not the BSD version.  Instead it's `ncat` from the nmap software.  Unlike the BSD version, there is no `-d` flag.  Instead of `-dl`, you can use `-l --recv-only < /dev/zero`.  The version of NCAT that comes with EL7 has a (closed/fixed) [bug](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/pull/151) that will close the program before finishing reading from the socket, if EOF is returned from reading stdin.  That's why you need to pass data into stdin via '/dev/zero' or something else.  The newer versions of NCAT support `--no-shutdown` which can be used in place of `< /dev/zero`.